# How to differentiate a 2-variable function with respect to a curve on the XY-plane?

Tags: real-analysis

I'm not very familiar with calculus of two variables.  I know you can take a partial derivative with respect to $x$ or $y$ and you can take a derivative with respect to a parameter $t$ where $z = f(x(t),y(t))$.  It occurred to me that I don't know how to take the partial derivative in an arbitrary direction, i.e. how to differentiate along a curve.  I thought the parametric derivative would allow this, but thinking about it again, I realized it's not that simple.  For example, say you want to take the derivative of $z = f(x,y)$ in the direction given by the line $y = x$.  How would this be done?

Answer (score 0):

The directional derivative $\nabla_w f$ in direction of the vector $w$ is given by

$$ \nabla_w f = \nabla f \cdot \frac{w}{|w|}$$

For $y=x$ the vector is $w=[x,y]^T=[x,x]^T=x[1,1]^T$.